# What is the purpose of this block in UC2854 based PFC circuits?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, current-measurement, boost, power-factor-correction

Below is a snippet from the datasheet of [UC2854](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uc2854b-ep).

[image]

**Current transformer senses the input current of PFC. But Rs also does the same. What is the square block shown here?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a full-wave bridge rectifier which powers the controller IC. The secondary of the transformer (above the rectifier) is most likely loosely coupled to the primary which is the series inductor for the PFC circuit. It is not a current monitor. It's a method of power harvesting which minimizes cost. Note that R1 supplies voltage to the controller at power up. There is an internal 20V zener diode between VCC and ground as shown in the block diagram in chapter 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/SLUA144) doc explains the reason.
"A secondary winding on the PFC boost inductor can be used to deliver a regulated auxiliary bias supply with few external components as shown in figure."

[image]
[image]